# Image layout using css

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I am trying to have three images in a row on the homepage of my website. This displays as I wanted on my machine but when trying it on other machines, the layout switches to 2 images on one row then the third on a new row. Heres the code:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>
            <!--<a href="#"><img src="tracylogo7.jpg" alt="Millington and Hope" /></a> -->
            <a href="#"><img src="tracylogoup6.jpg" alt="Millington and Hope" /></a>
        </h1>
        <h2>
            <!--<a href="#"><img src="tracylogo5_header.jpg" alt="Millington and Hope" /></a> -->
        </h2>   
    </div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="stock.html">Stock</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="box">
            <a href="#"><img src="home4.jpg" alt="Image 1" /></a>

            <a href="#"><img src="home_mir.jpg" alt="Image 2" /></a>

            <a href="#"><img src="home_urn.jpg" alt="Image 3" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <a href="#"><img src="tracylogosmall.jpg" alt="Logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p class="client">Tel: 07858740&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;E-mail: contact@millingtonandhope.com</p>

    </div>
</div>      
</body>
<style type="text/css">

html,body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body
{
    background:rgb(171,163,144);
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 600px;
}

#container
{
    margin:0 auto;
    background:rgb(171, 163, 144);
    width:80%;

}       


#header
{
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}


#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:25px;
   width:100%;
   background:rgb(151,143,124);
   border-top:solid 1px white;
}

.client
{
    color:white;
    margin:3px auto;
    text-indent:1cm;
    text-align:left;
}   

#sold
{
    color: red;
}

#box
{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:100px;
}
#box img
{
    margin:0 auto;
    border:solid 1px white;
    margin: 10px;
}

#box2
{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:260px;
    width: 100%;
}

#box2 img
{
    margin:0 auto;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);

}
```

Can anyone help me on how to fix this?

Comment: How shall we correct your css when you don't specify them ?

Comment: my css is included after the html. Does it not appear for you arkascha?

Comment: Are you talking about the images in "box"?

Comment: Yes, the images in "box"

Comment: @user1356791 Please Specify image's height & width So we can Solve your problem Friend

Answer (score 0):

The problem with horizontal float is that it is dependent on the width of the page (or browser window). Assuming you have the widths and heights of your images, make the height of the wrapper the height of the tallest image and make the width equal to the sum of the tree images' widths. This will prevent the page/window size from influencing the appearance.

However, as arkascha said, without viewing your CSS I cannot re-create the problem and must assume that it is a sizing issue.

Comment: My css is included after the html. Does it not appear for you guys?

Comment: sorry, it's better coding style to put it above. I didn't even see it. and I am going to stick with my solution. Reasoning: you have set your widths to 100% (meaning the entire page width) which does you no good if the page (or even the wrapper) is too narrow

Answer (score 0):

You have box defined as relative, which in the end means it takes into account things like browser size. Your best best is to definite everything as position absolutes, so that way they are ALWAYS at that position, no matter what. It'll cause scroll bars and the like if the images get too large and exceed the browser's size, but it would allow all 3 images to sit side by side in all window sizes.

Comment: Defining that div as absolute makes the div not centered but shifted to the right?

Comment: You'll have to play with the other CSS settings for that element since it now doesn't reference the elements around itself for positioning, thus the offset you see compared to what it was. It also wont center itself based off other elements around itself if I recall, given that it exists sort of in its own world onto itself, so things like aligning it to center wont work as well as giving it absolute X and Y co-ordinates to exist in.